# How to support scala collections in morphia?

Tags: scala, morphia

I used morphia before, and now I began to use scala. I found morphia can not support the collection type, such as List, ListBuffer, Set...

Is there any way to support this, like writing an extend class and register it or any existing jar have done this?

Comment: I nearly forgot adding comment about what I did at end:)

Comment: I used java collections at last. And use asScala convertion if I need closure support.Because the asScala method just creates an iterator and has no extra burden. If I need extra method support, I use implicit convertion.

Comment: Why not extend the morphia? Because after a period of research, I found the extendability of morphia is very poor. I must write lots of code, rewrite mapper, object factory and so on, and lots of test code.

Comment: Writing a simple ORM may be a good idea. The orm of mongo, in my favor, should consists of 3 parts: bson <=> object(DbObject <=> object also supported), mapper convention, fluent interfaces. Scala can do well, I believe.And later I will give a try.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration:

```
@Entity  
class User {    
  @Id
  var id: ObjectId = _;
  var name: String = _;
  var profiles: BSONObject = new BasicBSONList();
}
```

Save (assuming `ds` is a `Datastore`):

```
val me = new User()
me.name = "Hello" 
me.profiles = new BasicBSONList();
me.profiles.put("0", "str0");
me.profiles.put("4", "str1");
me.profiles.put("2", "str2");
ds.save[User](me)
```

Loading:

```
for (user <- ds.find(classOf[User]).asocial) {       
  log.log("" + user.name + "'s" + " profiles: " + user.profiles)       
}
```

Output:

```
me's profiles: [str0, null, str2, null, str1]
```

Comment: Thanks.But using a bsonObject type is not a good idea. it depends on the bson type which is not an original type in scala

Comment: In my use case I just happen not to use collection fields too much - only strings, numbers, timestamps, booleans. Linked data's id-s are transferred as a collection via JSON to client, where it is handled by a model.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asked about persisting Scala Collection objects using Morphia. @idonnie 's answer shows you how to persist BasicBSONList, which is a Java Collection object.